# How can I increment a number at the end of a string in bash?

Tags: bash

Basically i need to create a function where an argument is passed, and i need to update the number so for example the argument would be

version_2 and after the function it would change it to version_3

just increments by one

in java I would just create a new string, and grab the last character update by one and append but not sure how to do it in bash.

```
updateVersion() {
  version=$1
}
```

the prefix can be anything for example it can be dog12 or dog_12 and always has one number to update.

after the update it would be dog13 or dog_13 respectively.

Comment: Is that number always after an `_`?

Comment: Are you sure about your Java solution? `version_19` shouldn't be updated to `version_110`, right?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes.

Comment: @choroba Yes I would grab it convert to an int and do ++.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually I don't think so but the version will always have one number in it no other numbers so like version10 or version_11 etc.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `version` will be the prefix? (You've had at least one answer assuming as much).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No the prefix can be anything like it can be dog_12 or dog13 but would change to dog_13 and dog14 respectively I should have specified in the original post will update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
updateVersion()
{
    [[ $1 =~ ([^0-9]*)([0-9]+) ]] || { echo 'invalid input'; exit; }     
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1 ))"
}

# Usage
updateVersion version_11         # output: version_12
updateVersion version11          # output: version12
updateVersion something_else123  # output: something_else124
updateVersion "with spaces 99"   # output: with spaces 100

# Putting it in a variable
v2="$(updateVersion version2)"
echo "$v2"                       # output: version3
```

Comment: I picked this one because its the simplest one. You were all really good answers and I learned a lot thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use parameter expansion:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for version in version_1 version_19 version_34.14 ; do
    echo $version
    v=${version##*[^0-9]}
    ((++v))
    echo ${version%%+([0-9])}$v
done
```

`extglob` is needed for the `+([0-9])` construct which means "one or more digits".

Answer (score 3):

```
incrementTrailingNumber() {
  local prefix number
  if [[ $1 =~ ^(.*[^[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]+)$ ]]; then
    prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    number=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    printf '%s%s\n' "$prefix" "$(( number + 1 ))"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$1"
  fi
}
```

Usage as:

```
$ incrementTrailingNumber version_30
version_31
$ incrementTrailingNumber foo-2.15
foo-2.16
$ incrementTrailingNumber noNumberHereAtAll  # demonstrate noop case
noNumberHereAtAll
```

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party here, but there is an issue with the accepted answer.  It works for the OP's case where there are no numbers before the end, but I had an example like this:

`1.0.143`

For that, the regexp needs to be a bit looser.  Here's how I did it, preserving leading zeroes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

updateVersion()
{
  [[ ${1} =~ ^(.*[^0-9])?([0-9]+)$ ]]  && \
    [[ ${#BASH_REMATCH[1]} -gt 0 ]] && \
      printf "%s%0${#BASH_REMATCH[2]}d" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1 ))" || \
      printf "%0${#BASH_REMATCH[2]}d" "$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1))" || \
    printf "${1}"
}

# Usage
updateVersion 09          # output 10
updateVersion 1.0.450     # output 1.0.451
updateVersion version_01  # output version_02
updateVersion version12   # output version13
updateVersion version19   # output version20
```

Notes:

1. You only need to double-quote the first argument to `printf`.
2. Replace `${1}` with content in `""` if you want to use it on a command line,
   instead of in a function.
3. You can switch the last `printf` to a basic `echo` if you prefer.  If you are just printing to `stdout` or `stderr`, consider adding a newline (`\n`) at the end of each `printf`.
4. You can combine the function content into a single line, but it's harder to read.  It's better to break it into lines with `\` at every if (`&&`) and else (`||`), as above.

What the function does - line by line:

- Test the passed value ends with a number of one or more digits, optionally prefixed by at least one non-number.  Split into two groups accordingly (indexing is 1-based).
- When ending in a number, test there is a non-numeric prefix (i.e. length of group 1 > 0).
- When there are non-numerics, print group 1 (a string) followed by group 2 (an integer padded with zeroes to match the original string size).  Group 2 is base-10 converted and incremented by 1.  The conversion is important - leading zeroes are interpreted as octal by default.
- When there are only numbers, increment as above but just print group 2.
- If the input is anything else, return the supplied string.